# ADB push failed to copy, function not implemented

Tags: adb, genymotion

I cross compiled a library for my Android phone, and I keep getting the message when I try to push

```
failed to copy '/home/sanctus/Desktop/native-android-ports/libc-arm/crypt/libcrypt.so.1' to '/storage/sdcard0/ssh/crypt/libcrypt.so.1': Function not implemented
```

I am trying to push on to a genymotion emulator instance.

Comment: What query did you use to push the file? Post it as well.

Comment: 'adb shell /home/sanctus/open-ssh/ /storage/sdcard0/'

Comment: What kind of command is that? You pass 2 directory hanes to `adb shell`, where it won't find the first one (as it's not even on your device). Could it be you're confusing some things here?